# Display Additional Info

Tags: custom-field, user-meta

[image]

Hello guys, i have this problem. I added this additional field but i can't get the value for that specific field

I'm using this code but shows nothing:

```
($field['type'] === 'cedula' && !empty($course_id)) {
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                if (!empty($current_user)) {
                    $field['content'] = $current_user->"here should be the variable";
                }
```

And my code reference is this one:

```
($field['type'] === 'full_name' && !empty($course_id)) {
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                if (!empty($current_user)) {
                    $field['content'] = $current_user->user_firstname;
```

The thing is that i don't know how to show the field's value for the Additional User Information

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my question. In the DB there is a field in the wp_usersmeta table that saves that custom value. I went there and got the current meta_key for that field.

Comment: you can retrieve user meta with the `get_user_meta` function, _fields_ are the user facing name for _meta_